# ansible and postgres not allowing configuration: LOG: provided user name (postgres) and authenticated user name (boop) do not match

Tags: postgresql, ansible

Im trying to configure postgres with ansible. i have two vms running ubuntu 22.0.4.1 on an internal network. they are happy to use standard ansible commands. however upon using the standard ansible commands I get.

```
unable to connect to database: connection to server on socket \"/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432\" failed: fatal: peer authentication failed for user \"postgres\"
```

message.

the log says

```
DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 87: "local   all             postgres                                peer map=user_map"
LOG:  no match in usermap "user_map" for user "postgres" authenticated as "postgres"
FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

i used the following playbook:

```
---
- name: Setup
  hosts: postgres_primaries
  become: true

  tasks:

    - name: Install dependencies for PostgreSQL
      apt: 
        name: "{{ item.name }}" 
        update_cache: true 
        state: latest
      with_items:
        - { name: bash }
        - { name: openssl }
        - { name: libssl-dev }
        - { name: libssl-doc }
       
    - name: Install PostgreSQL 
      package: 
        name: "{{ item.name }}" 
        update_cache: true 
        state: present
      with_items:
        - { name: postgresql }
        - { name: postgresql-contrib }
        - { name: libpq-dev }
        - { name: python3-psycopg2 }
    - name: Ensure the PostgreSQL service is running
      service: name=postgresql state=started enabled=yes

    - name: Daemon-Reload for Postgres if case of config change
      systemd:
        state: restarted
        daemon-reload: yes 
        name: postgresql

- name: work on database
  hosts: postgres_primaries
  become_user: postgres
  vars_files:
    - vars.yml
  tasks:
    - name: create database
      postgresql_user:
        name: test1
        password: boop
```

i tried mapping boop to postgres the following user_name map:
`postgres boop postgres`

i tried editing my pg_hba.conf to a more catch all condition:

```
local all all peer map=user_map
```

this should give me a user but instead the aforementioned error turns up. if i try to add a `become: yes` to the final task i get a error related to moving files as an unprivileged user.

Comment: You don't show your username map being put into use.  What was your pg_hba line which used it?

Comment: sorry rookie error. i have tried implemnting it as followes

Comment: sorry rookie error. updated the files and it seems to be working but it is still failing the peer. I have updated the question to reflect the changes and the new log entry. am i correct that this should work between two vms on a nat network? thanks for showing interest.

Comment: The name of the map you are using (in the pg_hba) is "user_map", but the name of the map you show (from pg_ident) is "postgres".  So you are using an empty map, which must always fail.  Also, maybe you think that a username will always map to itself, but that is only the case when no map is in use.  When using a map, you must list a self-mapping in pg_ident if you want one to succeed.

Comment: Peer only works on "local" connections.  For network ("host") connections, you can use "ident" instead.  But that requires the other side to be running an identd daemon (which I believe is no longer common to do) and also I think it is not very secure as someone on your network could spoof it.